# нужно ли ставить тире

Tags: пунктуация

Лишиться чести - значит пойти против своих принципов.

Для человека чести быть предателем - самое страшное, что может быть.

Comment: В первом предложении что-то с логикой не так.

Comment: Это смотря какие принципы у человека. Люди-то разные....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Лишиться** чести ― **значит пойти** против своих принципов. Для человека чести **быть предателем** ― **самое страшное**, что может быть.

Тире ставится в обоих случаях. В первом предложении слово-связка ЗНАЧИТ, подлежащее и сказуемое выражены инфинитивом. Во втором предложении в роли сказуемого субстантивированное прилагательное с предметным значением "самое страшное".